Составной подчинительный союз. Пунктуация
Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении: "До того (,) как оказаться здесь, я и понятия не имел, что такое дом"?
В правилах сказано, что критериями постановки запятой являются логическое ударение на первую часть союза, наличие частицы или усилительного слова. Со вторым и третьим критериями всё ясно, но по поводу логического ударения у меня есть сомнения. Можно ли его поставить?

ТЕОРИЯ

Сложный союз составлен из местоименной и союзной части, например: Для того чтобы не быть заметным на снегу, заяц меняет цвет шкурки на белый. Но при определенных условиях может распадаться на исходные составляющие.

Союз в СПП — это показатель зависимости придаточного от главного и обычно относится к придаточному. Это чисто подчинительная (союзная) связь. Но при расчленении местоименная часть входит в главное предложение и на нее ставится ударение. Тогда значимость придаточного возрастает и связь по сути становится местоименно-союзной (взаимообусловленной).


Расчленение союза является обязательным  в следующих случаях:
(1) если подчинительный союз осложнён частицами, вводными 
или зависимыми словами;
(2) если придаточное предложение находится в однородных 
отношениях с другими членами предложения или с другими 
придаточными предложениями.

В других случаях расчленение составных подчинительных союзов факультативное и зависит от разных факторов:
(1) от взаимного положения главного и придаточного 
предложения;
(2) от относительной значимости главной или придаточной 
части.
При расчленении составного союза меняется интонация СПП, что 
позволяет ЛОГИЧЕСКИ подчеркнуть главную или придаточную 
часть.

РЕШЕНИЕ
(1) До того как оказаться здЕсь, // я и понятия не имел, / что такое дом.
Это основной вариант для придаточного в препозиции (по правилу Розенталя). Конструкция двухчастная.
(2) До тогО, / как оказаться здЕсь, // я и понятия не имел, что такое дОм.
Это вариант при логическом подчеркивании придаточного, ударением выделена местоименная часть союза.  Конструкция по-прежнему двухчастная, но теперь первая части делится на два фонетических отрезка произносительной паузой, а местоимение для того выделено дополнительным ударением.
Для расчленения союза в этой позиции желательно привести основания. Логическое подчеркивание местоимения до того можно объяснить по контексту, например:
Настоящего дома у меня никогда не было. До того, как оказаться здЕсь, я и понятия не имел, что такое дом.
ИНТЕРЕСНЫЙ ПРИМЕР

Это Справочник по пунктуации: До того(,) как
ДО ТОГО(,) КАК, союз.

Это вопрос по его содержанию с ответом:
 № 288844 До того, как проводить меня в этот Дом 
 колхозника, зашли сызнова к тебе. В. Распутин, Живи и 
 помни. До того как стать моим интендантом, он 
 прославился храбростью в славном литовском войске. Э. 
 Радзинский, Княжна Тараканова. Почему в первом 
 предложении запятая перед "как" ставится, а во втором 
 предложении не ставится?

ОТВЕТ. До того как – составной подчинительный союз. Он 
может целиком входить в придаточную часть (и не 
разделяться запятой), а может расчленяться, в этом случае 
запятая ставится между частями союза. Поэтому возможны 
оба варианта: с запятой и без запятой.

Если говорить о некоторых закономерностях, то можно 
отметить следующее. Если придаточная часть 
сложноподчиненного предложения предшествует главной (как 
в приведенных Вами примерах), составной подчинительный 
союз чаще не расчленяется. Но и постановка запятой 
ошибкой не будет.


А где же однозначность решения, чем различаются варианты? И какой вариант у В. Распутина?  Мне попался текст без расчленения.
А дальше, дальше-то помнишь, Андрей? Дальше-то — умора. 
До того как проводить меня в этот Дом колхозника, зашли 
сызнова к тебе. Знаем, что старуха теперь добрее... 



По контексту можно решить, что логическое подчеркивание нужно, этот вариант в Справочнике. С другой стороны, у нас нераспространенное придаточное в препозиции, да и сам союз небольшого объема, тогда лучше не расчленять его на части.  Здесь решение за автором.
